# what would the AL32UTF8 charset of oracle represented in mysql

Tags: mysql, oracle, character-encoding

If I were to run a query such as:

```
select o.col1, m.col1 from oracle_tab o, mysql_tab@mysql m where o.col1=m.col1;

insert into oracle_tab (select * from mysql_tab@mysql);
```

what would the corresponding charset for mysql if AL32UTF8 was used in the oracle db?

from mysql website these are the choices:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-charsets.html

This is what I'm getting from oracle db if i ran

```
SELECT * FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS
```

> PARAMETER VALUE
>
> 1 NLS_LANGUAGE    AMERICAN
>
> 2 NLS_TERRITORY   AMERICA
>
> 3 NLS_CURRENCY    $
>
> 4 NLS_ISO_CURRENCY    AMERICA
>
> 5 NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS  .,
>
> 6 NLS_CHARACTERSET    AL32UTF8
>
> 7 NLS_CALENDAR    GREGORIAN
>
> 8 NLS_DATE_FORMAT DD-MON-RR
>
> 9 NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE   AMERICAN
>
> 10    NLS_SORT    BINARY
>
> 11    NLS_TIME_FORMAT HH.MI.SSXFF AM
>
> 12    NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT    DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM
>
> 13    NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT  HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
>
> 14    NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
>
> 15    NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY   $
>
> 16    NLS_COMP    BINARY
>
> 17    NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS    BYTE
>
> 18    NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP FALSE
>
> 19    NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  AL16UTF16
>
> 20    NLS_RDBMS_VERSION   11.2.0.1.0

Answer (score 3):

Based on a brief reading of Oracle's AL32UTF8, I think that corresponds to MySQL's utf8mb4.  Both handle Emoji and Chinese.

Meanwhile, Oracle's UTF8 may be the same as MySQL's utf8 *for the "basic plane" characters* -- which are encoded in no more than 3 bytes.

If you would care to present the hex of some characters (and the graphics for them) that you have, we can further assess the situation.